Automatic builds for Android app (Kotlin, Gradle). What is needed and how to stay up to date?
I'm quite new to Android development and I just developed an Android App using Android Studio. It is a Kotlin app building with gradle.
Beside my development machine, I want to have a build only machine which is only building and signing the app (.abb) using a makefile (if git repo has changed). On my development machine, it already builds nice using gradlew command. I want this to be outsourced.
Question 1
I currently have a Mac machine available, so what do I have to install to let my app build and sign on a Mac without installing full Android studio?
Question 2
I also want to keep the needed components from question 1 up to date (Kotlin, Java, Gradle, other tools). What is the recommended procedure to keep all needed components up to date without comparing and downloading versions manually? On my Linux I'm used to do apt-get upgrade or zypper up. But how on Mac?
Side note: Android Studio helps in keeping everything up to date. But it is a huge package just for keeping stuff up to date, right?

Do you want to say , How one can build an android app ( using source code )  without using android studio

@Rudra Yeah, but a bit more. What will I need and how to keep it updated. All on MacOS.

Android studio is an official ide used to build android apps , provided by google , You can enjoy building apps without android studio too with the help of AGP ( gradle ) independent of any platform , you need to be in touch with the repositories ( agp , kotlin , etc ) for stable releases for android.

@Rudra Your answer brings me back to my questions. How to know what to download  and how to keep that updated?
